# Advice on recording Water Meter Reading Data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm working on a Water Monitoring System which the customer can pay and monitor their bills. It has 3 users the customers, admin and reading officer. If a customer application for water connection is approved he/she will be given an water meter with a number so the reader can determined which meter it was associated.

The formula for water consumption is (Previous Reading - Current Reading) my problem is how should I stored those data should I used only one table that has "ID, Meter No., Cubic, Liters" Or have an table named " Meter Number" that has only one customer water meter reading info (one table one customer) I dont know how to construct it.

If a new Current Reading is occurred that last Current Reading will become a Previous Reading. How can I do that?

How can I also get that previous value of a row since it is containing the Previous Reading?

Thanks!

Comment: There's obviously multiple approaches but I would recommend to have at least a separate table for readings (reading id, date/time, meter number or id and the registered data). From there you can associate the reading with a meter table which in its turn is associated with a customer table (either a 1-to-1 or 1-to-many depending on your requirements). You could use the date/time to retrieve the last 2 readings of a meter/customer in your application and then you'll have the current and previous ones.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. May I ask if the "registered data" is the reading information I get from the meter? And I'm not sure what data should be stored in the meter table.  My customers table has this columns (ID, AccNo, Firstname, LastnName, Age, Sex, HoseNo., Municipality, State, Phone No., Email, Password, Status, Class)

Comment: Indeed, with "registered data" I was referring to reading information such as cubic, liters, etc. For the association, you could add the meter number and customer ID to the reading table, which would leave you with only 2 tables. However in my experience having a table for meter is much more flexible (for example. what if you would need to track when a meter was installed or removed at a customer). Either way you should choose what best fits your needs ofcourse